# discrete fourier transform circular symmetry

Tags: dft, convolution, symmetry

I was reading digital signal processing. In topic Discrete Fourier Transform, circular symmetry it is said that circular advance is obtained by shifting x(n) in clockwise direction. i.e. to obtain x(n+k) Shift sequence x(n) in CW direction by k samples.

my question is would it same for x(-n+k)?

circular fold x(n) to obtain x(-n) and shift sequence x(-n) in CW direction by k samples. am i right?

*CW=Clock Wise

Comment: saying "clockwise" for a circular operation isn't something I'm used to – I just say "shift forward by $k$" ($\hat x(n) = x((n-k)\mod N)$ ), or backwards ($\hat x(n) = x((n+k)\mod N)$, with $N$ being the length of the structure). For clockwise, you'd need to have a "geometric" interpretation of the ring structure, and I don't see how that'd be unambiguous

Comment: yes geometrical makes no sense. i have found the solution. for x(-n+k) first shift x(n) by k sample and reverse to get x(-n+k). i have wasted too much time for this..